Receiving 'Provided module can't be loaded.' error
Attempting to deploy Function App in Google Cloud and receiving this error highlighting inability to load kafkajs package. kafkajs is listed with other dependencies in the Function App directory's package.json file:
{
    "dependencies": {
      "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.0.0",
      "kafkajs": "^2.1.0",
      "node-fetch": "^3.0.0"
    }
}

Tried testing/deploying with NodeJS version 16-20 (included 22 preview). Completed manual npm install in Cloud Shell. kafkajs documentation indicates there shouldn't be version incompatibility. No indications that the Artifact Registry is causing the issue.
Also, validated kafkajs is installed with a ls node_module command in Cloud Shell.
